# Is it advisable to have "pure" model objects additionally to managed objects?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have seen in some (REST) iOS apps that they use "pure" model object, e.g. "Product", core data object, e.g. "ProductCore", and an object to represent the remote objects e.g. "ProductJSON".

I myself usually also use this architecture, I think it leads to clear separation of concerns. It has also some practical benefits, for example there are situations in which I want to create a model object but not add it to core data yet. Or others where I want to send the models directly to the server and not store them in core data.

On the other side, it consumes more memory and I have to maintain more classes. It's also not necessary for a memory cache as core data has one. Temporary objects (e.g. form data which hasn't been validated yet) can also be deleted without performance issues, as managed objects are only in memory until saved. There are also not portability benefits, as anything that understands Swift/ObjC also understands core data... extensibility can be achieved at least with extensions. Maybe subclassing.

So I was wondering, is there an overall preferred way to setup model clases in applications? In which context does an additional layer with pure model objects make sense, where is it an overkill?

Edit: **I don't consider this an "opinion based" question**. The optimal architecture can be different depending on the requirements, but which is one better under which circumstances should be able to be determined based on facts.

Comment: Also consider using the additional resources to write more/better tests. I'm a fan of "pure" models; they can also be over-complicated, especially in an inherently non-pure context.

Comment: Well, mapping managed objects to pure models and the other way around is usually straight forward... and automatable. and then just ensure that the app always uses only the pure models... testing is a good point though, don't have a lot of experience with that yet but I imagine it can be easier using pure models, particularly creating mock data.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is meant by a pure object. Here is what I am doing:

1. Service model represents the data sent to and received from web services, and corresponds to their JSON payloads. I write adapters to map JSON to service models and vice versa.
2. Entity models represent persistent data. These are the Core Data classes corresponding to my data model, and inherit from NSManagedObject.
3. View models represent data displayed in a view. Each view has its own view model. This approach maps the view model precisely to the view. An adapter class builds the view model from entity models and/or service models (if the data to be displayed is not persistent). The adapter shapes the data to the view, and does things like formatting dates to simplify the job of the view controller.

A table view cell, for example, might display elements from several entity models. The view model would contain a class representing the data to be displayed in each cell, and the adapter would build one for each cell. Populating the table view cell in the view controller becomes a very simple task of mapping one-to-one between view model and cell fields.

This approach might seem overkill, but I have found it to be extremely effective and worth the effort. It greatly simplifies the code in the view controllers, and makes testing easier.

Comment: The approach with "view models" is commonly known as a "Model-View-ViewModel" design pattern, there have been many articles on its usage for iOS apps lately.

Comment: Great! I have heard of this pattern but wasn't sure if it was the same thing. There are many variations on how to solve this. I've followed this approach in Winforms before and liked it a lot. It seemed natural to try it in iOS.